# How to open a port in Windows using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, firewall

My windows system has the firewall enabled.

I would like to allow incoming connections on a particular port (say: 4546).

Is there a ruby library that can help me do this ?

Detail:
I have a sinatra application (webserver) running on port 4546. I needed to bring down the firewall in order for it to work.
I am looking for a way to not keep the port 4546 under the firewall list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with this:

```
require 'socket'               # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.open(4546)  # Socket to listen on port 4546
loop {                         # Servers run forever
  client = server.accept       # Wait for a client to connect
  client.puts(Time.now.ctime)  # Send the time to the client
  client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
  client.close                 # Disconnect from the client
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting.

Well the exact issue is I have a web server running on port 4546. But I needed to bring down the firewall in order for it to work.

Would this work ?

Comment: You will have to add an exception to Firewall for this port.

Comment: Fire these commands on command line or run from Ruby:

netsh firewall add portopening protocol=TCP port=4546 name=”Web Server (TCP 4546)” mode=ENABLE 

netsh firewall reset